# Swift Error: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '((String), ())'

Tags: swift, xcode7

What am I doing wrong here? I am stuck. I am making a image posting application. Everything works fine until I post something. When I write a caption and select a image it will not let me post it because of this error. Am I writing the code wrong? Please help!

```
func loadData() {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?)  -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            //No error

            if let posts = posts as [PFObject]? {
                for post in posts {

                    self.images.append(post["Image"] as! PFFile)
                    self.imageCaptions.append(post["Caption"] as! String)
                    self.imageDates.append(post["date"] as! String) // Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '((String), ())'
                    self.imageUsers.append(post["addedBy"] as! String)

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        } else {
            //Error
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What line does the error occur at? And what are you trying to accomplish with this code specifically? You say it's to post a post to the server, but you are downloading data with the code you supplied.

Comment: It occurs here: "self.imageDates.append(post["date"] as! String)"